# CreateFile() failed with error code 32 while reading pendrive

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, usb

I am trying to read raw bytes from a pen drive 'E:', but it gives error code 32 when trying to open the drive using `CreateFIle()`. My code is as follows:

```
wchar_t  wszDrive[7];
wszDrive[0] = '\\';
wszDrive[1] = '\\';
wszDrive[2] = '.';
wszDrive[3] = '\\';
wszDrive[4] = 'e';
wszDrive[5] = ':';
wszDrive[6] = '\0';

hDevice = CreateFile(wszDrive,  //drive name to open                        

        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,   ////must be opened with exclusive access(No Sharing)
        0,                              // no access to the drive
        NULL,             // default security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,    // disposition i.e. if file already exist
        0,                // file attributes
        NULL);            // do not copy file attributes

if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // cannot open the drive
{
    printf("CreateFile() failed! from read with error %d.\n", GetLastError());// Program prints this line. with error code 32.
    return (FALSE);
}
else
    cout << "\nCreateFile() successful! in read";
```

Edit:
The `CreateFile()` runs fine without errors if I use `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE`:

```
hDevice = CreateFile(wszDrive,                                            
                        GENERIC_READ | 
                        GENERIC_WRITE,
                        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                        NULL,             
                        OPEN_EXISTING,    
                        0,                
                        NULL);
```

Why cannot I run with exclusive access?

Comment: I dont understand, is your problem compilation or CreteFile fail?

Comment: Program compiles but CreateFile() fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 32 is [`ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-).

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

It means there is already an open handle to the drive, and that handle is using access/sharing rights which are not compatible with the access/sharing rights you are requesting.

That is why you can't open the drive for exclusive access, but you can open it for read/write sharing - the drive is already open elsewhere for reading/writing.

If you want to know where exactly, you can use a tool like [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see which processes have open handles to which files/folders, devices, etc.

Comment: In particular, when a volume device is mounted by a filesystem, the filesystem controls direct volume access and creates a Volume Control Block (VCB), which, like a File Control Block (FCB), has a share-access record that tallies access and shared access for all opens. In addition to a normal `IoCheckShareAccess`, a volume open that does not share write and delete access is exclusive, which locks the volume and disables read-access sharing if write access is requested. If an exclusive volume open doesn't share read access, the volume and *files on it* cannot be open already, even for reading.

Comment: For example, see [`FatOpenVolume`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/create.c#L2277) in the published fastfat filesystem driver.